# Facing issue while rendering the Partial view using JQuery

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Area like below.

[image]

**Below are the Controller actions.**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index_partial()
{
    return PartialView("_PartialPage1");
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    AdminModule model = new AdminModule();
    model.MyName = "My Name";
    return View("Index", model);
}
```

**View**

```
@model _1.Areas.Admin.Models.AdminModule
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_LayoutPage1.cshtml";
}
<h2>
    Index</h2>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js">
</script>
<div id="myForm">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <p id="pid">
        </p>
        <input onclick="ClickHere();" type="submit" value="Button" />
    }
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function ClickHere() {
        debugger;
            var url = '@Url.Action("Index_partial", "Admin")';
            $('#p').load("@Url.Action("Index_partial", "Admin")");
        }

    </script>
</div>
```

===================================

**Partial View**

```
@model _1.Areas.Admin.Models.AdminModule
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "Admin", 
             new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myForm", HttpMethod = "Post" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(i => i.MyName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.MyName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.MyName)
    <p id="getDateTimeString">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Click here" id="btn" />
}
```

=====================================

In the View, I have a button, on clicking it should render the Partial View in

```
<p id="pid"></p>
```

**Issue is - on clicking the button is navigating the page to Partial View, It should instead render the Partial View Html in p tag. How to do this ?**

Comment: at the first glance i guess you need to cancel the submit event but returning false in your javascript function

Comment: @SMC: You can answer your own question instead of modifying an existing answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View should be like this...

```
<div id="myForm">
    <p id="pid">
    </p>
</div>
<input id="BTN" type="submit" value="Button" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $('#BTN').click(function(){
        $('#pid').load("@Url.Action("Index_partial", "Admin")");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the `@using (Html.BeginForm())`
2. Add an id to your button

:

```
< input onclick="ClickHere();" type="submit" id="Button" value="Button" />
```

3. reassign your click event to unobtrusive rather than in-line:

:

```
$('#Button').click(function(){
       debugger;
            var url = '@Url.Action("Index_partial", "Admin")';
            $('#p').load("@Url.Action("Index_partial", "Admin")");
        }
```

1. change your return partial

:

```
return PartialView("_PartialPage1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `@using (Html.BeginForm())` and add this bit of HTML:

```
<p id="pid"></p>

<button type="button" id="mybtn">Load partial view</button>
```

and then, add a bit o jQuery:

```
(function() {
    $('#mybtn').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index_partial", "Admin")',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                $('#pid').empty().html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This is not impacting my code `public PartialViewResult Index_partial()`

Comment: This is nore required `@using (Html.BeginForm())`.

Comment: Sure... you can remove that.

Comment: Finally i should remove the script and button from `<div id="myForm">`

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index_partial()
{
    return PartialView("_PartialPage1");
}
```

Inside the view/javascript.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ClickHere() {
        $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action(MVC.Admin.Index_partial())",
        async: false,
        data: { },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#pid").empty();
            $("#pid").html(data);
        }
    });
    }
</script>
```

I use [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/) to generate the url.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Home Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PartialView()
{
   return this.PartialView("PartialView");
}
```

View

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {

            $("#renderedHtml").load('Home/PartialView');

        });

    });

</script>


    <div id="renderedHtml"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Get Partial" id="btnSubmit" />
```